# Multivariable Calculus Differential Equations

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We admit that the set:
$$ S=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3 : x \gt 0, y \gt 0, ln \frac{x+y}{2}+3xy=(1+x^2)z+y^4z^3\}$$

can be seen as the graph $\{(x,y,z)\}\in \mathbb{R}^3:z=f(x,y)\}$ of a differntial function $f(x,y)$ with domain $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: x \gt 0, y\gt 0 \}.$

Find $a = f(1,1).$

How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Just plug in $x=y=1$ and $z=a$ into the defining equation of $S$ and solve.